# Python: Conditionally create new keys in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries looking like this:

```
[
{'stim': 'I', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 0},
{'stim': 'nev,er.', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 0},
{'stim': 'he,si,ta,te', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 1},
{'stim': 'while', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 1},
{'stim': 'dri,ving', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 0}, etc.]
```

What I want to obain is the following result:

```
[
    {'stim': 'I', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 0},
    {'stim': 'nev', 'stim1':'er.','condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 0},
    {'stim': 'he', stim1:'si', stim2:'ta', stim3:'te.', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 1},
    {'stim': 'while', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 1},
    {'stim': 'dri','stim1': 'ving.', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 0}, etc.]
```

Only when a word is hyphenated by a comma value, I need the code to create additional keys which are combined with the (remaining)syllable values. I am fairly new to programming, and I do not get much further than:

```
for dict in list:
    if "," in (dict['stim']):
        dict.update({'word1':'syllable'})
```

I don't know how to add the required amount of keys. I also don't succeed in getting the actual syllable in the corresponding values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use names like `list` and `dict` in your code; these mask the built-in types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for d in inputlist:
    words = d['stim'].split(',')
    d['stim'] = words[0]
    d.update(('stim{}'.format(i), word) for i, word in enumerate(words[1:], 1))
```

This replaces `d['stim']` with the first value of a split on `,` (which could be just one element if there are no commas present). Then the dictionary is updated with a sequence of key-value pairs, generated from the rest of the words and their indices (starting at 1).

Comment: I used your code, did some operations and want to go back to a list of dictionaries of the initial form. So now, I have: `{'stim': 'he', stim1:'si', stim2:'ta', stim3:'te.', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2':...}`, and I want to ga back to `{'stim': 'hesitate', 'condition1': 0, 'condition2': 1, 'condition3': 1}.` Indeed, the word does not contain comma values anymore. I wrote the following, but that doesn't work: `for d inputlist: if 'word1' in d: stim_order['word'].append(stim_order['word1']) del stim_order[word1]`and I repeated this sequence for word 2, 3 & 4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KnRm: Strings are not lists; `stim_order['word'] += stim_order['word1']` would work better..

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I don't quite understand. I thought I was appending a string to another string?  What does your answer, I never came across `+=`, actually mean?

Comment: @KnRm: You are *concatenating* a string. Also, `list.append()` alters the list in-place, but strings are immutable (you cannot alter them in-place, you need to create a new string constructed from two inputs); the same applies to tuples. `target += value` is the same as `target = target + value` when target is immutable.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I'm now encountering `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`.

Comment: Clearly, you mixed lists and dictionaries somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dict in list:
    if "," in (dict['stim']):
        result = dict['stim'].split(',') # get a list of individual syllables
        dict['stim'] = result.pop(0) # store the first syllable in the existing dict key
        for index, syllable in enumerate(result, 1): #for every other syllable update dict
            dict['stim'+str(index)] = syllable})
```

I would change the names of dict and list. I left them so they match your sample code.

Comment: Why use `.update()` for a dictionary with one key? Then you can just do `dict['stim' + str(index)] = syllable` instead..